# Putting boolean values in the Model $fillable property is prevent them from working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Running some tests that keep failing on some boolean inputs to the model. I basically run a test where I submit an entity to the database, pull it back out and make sure they match.

The booleans keep failing when I put them into the $fillable property of the model. To my understanding you needed to put all expected inputs in there. These boolean properties are coming from checkbox inputs.

```
class Contract extends Model {
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'contracts';
protected $guarded = ['id'];

protected $casts = [
    'is_volunteer' => 'boolean',
    'tpp_accepted' => 'boolean',
    'is_old_law' => 'boolean'
];

protected $fillable = [     
    //'is_volunteer',       
    //'is_old_law',     
    //'tpp_accepted',
    'created_by_user',
    'client_db_id',
    ...

/*
 *  Turn a check box value into a bool
 */
protected function checkBoxToBoolean($value): bool {
    return ( !!$value ) ? true : false;
}
```

Example of one checkbox's mutator/accessor

```
    public function getTppAcceptedAttribute($value): bool { 
        return (bool) $value;
    }


    public function setTppAcceptedAttribute($value) {   
         $this->attributes['tpp_accepted'] = $this->checkBoxToBoolean($value);
    }
```

The database blueprint ...

```
class CreateContractsTable extends Migration {

    public function up() {
        Schema::create('contracts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();           
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('created_by_user')->nullable();          
        $table->boolean('is_volunteer')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('is_old_law')->default(false);          
        $table->boolean('tpp_accepted')->default(false);
        ...
```

A helper method I use to check what values are different between an existing model and an array.

```
/*
 *  Return changed values
 */
public function getDiff(array $compare): array {
    
    $compareModel = self::make($compare);       
    
    $diff = array_diff_assoc($compareModel->attributes, $this->attributes);
    
    foreach(self::getNonInputKeys() as $k) 
        unset($diff[$k]);           
        
    return $diff;
}
```

What am I missing here, is putting boolean inputs into the $fillable property bad/incorrect practice. Why does it work when they are omitted. Everything works except the bools lol.

Comment: failing how? you are not showing anything related to filling a model with attributes here ... also why do you have a mutator and an accessor for an attribute that is being cast? ... your `checkBoxToBoolean` method is doing this: `bool ? true : false` which is redundant, btw

Comment: They're always coming out false from the model. I've got the mutators and accessors are a hurry up and work damn it solution.

Comment: you have not shown us how you are creating the model instances with attributes or using those attributes, the default value for all those bools is `false` so perhaps you are not passing any of those attributes to the database

Answer (score -1):

So I triangulated the problem. Here are my findings from the "setting and getting bools through the Laravel model" rabbit hole.

1 - When setting a bool value, it wouldn't work unless I used a mutator to convert it into a 0 or 1 int, **not a bool**. I believe in the database a boolean value is just a TINTINT(1) value, and this maybe why a 0 or 1 is needed.

```
protected function checkBoxToBoolean($value) {
    return ( (bool) $value ) ? 1 : 0;    
}

public function setClientActiveAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['client_active'] = $this->checkBoxToBoolean($value);
}
```

2 - Yes make sure your bool key(s) is in the $fillable array property of the model if you're using mass alignment (which I am sure most people are).

```
protected $fillable = [
    'client_id',
    'client_active' <- ...
```

3 - Add your bool key(s) into the $casts property of the model

```
protected $casts = [
    'client_active' => 'boolean'
];
```

4 - Model values are accessed how you declare them. Not as camel case! Which is where I screwed up

```
$myBoolValue = $model->client_active
```

NOT

```
$myBoolValue = $model->clientActive
```

I am new to Laravel and most things are converted back and forth from camel case, so this was a gotcha for me. I hope this helps others save a few hours.

Comment: The whole point of the `$casts` property is to automatically do the cast, you do not need to use mutators. Database columns are always accessed as defined. If you had provided the debugging information requested in the question comments it's likely you could have been pointed in a more productive direction.

Comment: If I remove the mutator, my tests fail because only false is returned. I am setting the model with mass alignment